# Is it possible to publish arbitrary JUnit results to SonarQube?

Tags: jenkins, junit, sonarqube

I am running sitespeed.io tests in Jenkins, and have configured it to output junit format test results.

I'd now like to publish those test results to SonarQube (I realise I can publish them in Jenkins, but I have a requirement to keep everything in one place as much as possible).

However, when I add the test results file into the Sonar analysis (using `sonar.junit.reportsPath=/path/to/sitespeed-results`, having named my results file `TESTS-sitespeed.xml`) SonarQube doesn't seem to show any results on its dashboard.

I understand that SonarQube also has a setting to configure the location of test files, and this is often cited as a reason for test results not being ingested correctly, and that leads me to wonder whether what I'm trying to do is possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Jez

Comment: Do you check the permission on the /path/to/sitespeed-results? Check if the sonar user can read the xml files.

Comment: I'm using the SonarQube scanner for Jenkins plugin (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Jenkins) which uses Sonar Runner behind the scenes. That's triggered by the same process that creates the results file, so I think permissions should be OK. Certainly I don't see any errors in the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the property `sonar.junit.reportsPath` will read and parse the report but will only save the information if the class name indicated by the report can be mapped back to a java resource of the project.
I have no idea about the output of your test in surefire format but I sense the classname won't match any resource of your project and so your report is parsed but data is ignored.

Comment: You're right - there won't be a resource to match. It seems like this isn't possible. Thanks very much.